# Save Location of Dragged Element - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a template where a user can drag programmable IOT items around in a room and save the template. As you will see in the code below the room is simply a `div` with a background image which the user has uploaded to the server. When the user opens the page again at a later time, I want to be able to load the dragged items in their saved positions. I understand how to save the data, I don't know how actually calculate where the item should be displayed on the screen in a multi-browser compatible format. I'm using the jQuery UI for dragging the IOT devices around the room.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="room" class="room" style="background-image:url('<%= url_for(@room.background) %>')">
            <div class="device draggable">
                <div class="content md">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

Comment: Did you try [jQuery.position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) ?

Comment: you need to add some position with all your rooms and order them by position and save them when drag

Comment: You can use jQuery Cookies to store the div position, even after refresh also, you can able to see the positions of the div at the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `x` and `y` coordinate in the drag event and persist it as shown below.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            x = this.offsetLeft / (body.clientWidth - $this.width()),
            y = this.offsetTop / (body.clientHeight - $this.height());
    }
});
```

While user open page again, later on, you can assign `left` and `top` property for the element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("draggable").style.left = (body.clientWidth - $shape.width()) * x + "px";
document.getElementsByClassName("draggable").style.top = (body.clientHeight - $shape.height()) * y + "px";
```

Here, `body` means `window.document.body`. This is what I have done to calculate the position when I want to persist the position and it works for all scenarios like browser if restored or maximize and for also for all the browsers.